# How to Import non npm dependency in angular

Tags: javascript, angular5, jsplumb

I am working on angular 5 project want to create a visualization of an application system internal connection (something like a flowchart where systems internal components like server, mq, db can be dragged upon and connection be made) component in angular. Started with the jsplumb community edition ([link](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/download)) to do the same. Was able to successfully integrate jsplumb into angular 5 application. The only drawback is we cannot create the new element at runtime (That is drag and drop items and create connection). This is possible in the toolkit licenced version. Which I am not considering to work with.

So was looking into js-graph-it ([link](http://file:///D:/iCTES/angular5/ui-modelling/js-graph-it_1.1/js-graph-it_1.1/index.html)) The js-graph-it is a old project works nicely with simple html page. I am having problem injecting js-graph-it.js file into the angular project. As it is non npm file it is not defined and the system does not recognize the same if syntax like `import { jsgt } from '../../assets/jsgraphit/js` is used. If you observer I have placed the files in my asset folder. **The first question is this the right place for 3rd party js file if not present in npm?** **How to import or the correct way to import such files not present in npm ?**

Comment: same question in my project with Jasper visualize.js lib ... did you have any chance to find a solution? currently I'm planning to create my own npm dependency but it's quite heavy to do so!

Answer (score 1):

You can import 3rd party JS files into your project and be bundled by the CLI by putting them in the `scripts` array in your `angular-cli.json` config file.

This will make them part of the global scope (e.g. available on the `window` object) as if you imported it via a `<script>` tag.

You can additionally include any CSS files or other assets part of the libraries in the config file as well via the `styles` and `assets` properties.

I think the proper way for you to manage these 3rd party libs is to store them in your assets directory as it looks like you are already doing.